# Ошибка object has no attribute 'object_list'

Tags: django-view

Ошибка

/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/pp-lX8UY0eG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py in get_context_data, line 115

AttributeError: 'OrderCreateView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

До этого работало всё ок, изменения в views.py не вносил, а сегодня такая ошибка

```
class OrderCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CustomSuccessMessageMixin, CreateView, ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = OrderForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('orders')
    success_msg = 'Заказ сохранён'
    # this method will pass 'user' as param in kwargs to form __init__()
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(OrdersInfoView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] =  self.request.user
        return kwargs
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['list_orders'] = Order.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        kwargs['customer_form'] = CustomerOrderForm
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        new_number = self.object.author.order_set.count() + 1
        self.object.number_order = str(new_number)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил в models.py и forms.py новое поле, а в шаблоне в форме это поле забыл написать.
Соответственно одного атрибута не хватало. Может кому-то будет полезен этот ответ.